Covariance matrix of sliding windows of a time series
I have a non-stationary time series $\{X_t\}$ (it is a stock price) and from this set I collect sliding windows of length 400 timesteps $\{Y^i_\tau\}$ where $i$ labels the window and $\tau \in [1,400]$. The reason why I am selecting sliding windows is that I want to compare a naive sampling approach against another one that I am using (much more complicated).
I am interested in measuring the covariance (or auto-covariance) matrix
$$
\text{cov}(\tau,\tau') = E\left[ \left(Y_\tau - \bar{Y}_\tau\right)\left(Y_{\tau'} - \bar{Y}_{\tau'}\right) \right]
$$
where $\bar{Y}_\tau$ is the mean of the observations of each sliding window at (relative) timestep $\tau$.
I have computed an estimate of the covariance matrix ($N$~10K sliding windows) with the following formulae
$$
\bar{Y}_\tau = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Y^i_\tau
$$
$$
\text{cov}(\tau,\tau') = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[
\left(Y^i_\tau - \bar{Y}_\tau\right)\left(Y^i_{\tau'} - \bar{Y}_{\tau'}\right) \right]
$$
and I have plotted a heatmap, which is the following

This is nearly the result that I was expecting (neighbors observations are more closely correlated the farest ones), except that the covariance matrix results higher for observations at late times of each sliding window. In the plot, you can see that the color of the diagonal becomes warmer as we move to the right. I can't understand why I am seeing this effect. I thought about possible reasons:

The series is not stationary, mean and variance change over time. However, I am selecting sliding windows, so observations at late times will be present in early times of subsequent windows.
Boundary effects: I don't see how these can be relevant as I have ~10K sliding windows and the window size is not that big.
The estimator for the covariance matrix is wrong. This can be the reason... How would I estimate the covariance matrix in this case?

Do you have any insight?

you've really calculated covariance, and not correlation? If so, it gets higher over time because stock prices generally increase over time.

@JohnMadden, variance and covariance are both about deviations from the mean. If the mean is growing but deviations are not, covariance/variance should not grow.

@Richard But that's rarely how growth works, does it?  Deviations tend to be proportional to means, or at least to some positive power of the means.

@JohnMadden Thanks for the comment. However, if there is a growth at late time in a window, the same growth will be present at early times of another window. So I don't understand how this can explain the asymmetry I am noticing in the plot.

@apt45: you want to work with returns when doing any kind of analysis such as this because returns are atleast much closer to being stationary ( constant mean which is also a stretch but not as bad as constant prices ) compared to prices. Also, volatility of a stock depends on the magnitude when dealing with prices which is not ideal. By this I mean that a 1 percent change in a 10 dollar stock is 10 cents but a 1 percent change in a 100 dollar stock is 1 dollar. So, it's definitely best to work in returns rather than dollars.

@mlofton shouldn’t the covariance matrix of returns be trivial? That’s why I am not working with returns.

@whuber, sure. My point was that the focus on the mean is misleading. The focus should be on deviations form the mean.

apt45: I'm not sure why the covariance matrix of returns is trivial. To be honest,  this sliding window approach makes me confused as far as how you're calculating covariance matrices ? I don't know what you mean by $N \sim 10K$ sliding windows. Also, what is going on with the sliding window ? Are you calculating returns using sliding windows ? How wide is each window ?
